# Index of subgroup inside subgroup of finite index

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup of finite index. Everywhere I look it says that if $K$ is a subgroup of $H$ then $K$ has finite index in $H$. However, nowhere can I find that discusses why this is true.

Comment: Please provide an explicit, complete quote (and citation) of at least one place you looked at which stated this.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Proof 1 at: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Tower_Law_for_Subgroups "By hypothesis, $q = |H:K|$ is finite".

Comment: You are misreading what that link says. They have two proofs. In the first one, the **assume** that both indices are finite. In the second one, they **assume** that $G$ is finite.  In neither one do they have an overarching assumption that $[G:H]$ is finite, nor do they conclude from such an assumption that $[H:K]$ finite is a *conclusion*.  Simply put: that link does not say what you think it says.

Comment: (While the tower law is true for cardinals, many books only state it with index either finite or $\infty$; if $[G:K]$ is infinite, then by their first proof you conclude that at least one of $[G:H]$ and $[H:K]$ is infinite. If $[G:K]$ is finite you can reduce to the case of $G$ finite and apply the second proof in your link)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Two proofs, but one theorem. They assume there is a group $G$, a finite index subgroup $H$, and a subgroup $K$ of $H$. There is no assumption on the index of $K$.

Comment: You are still misinterpreting what the page says; and you said “everywhere.” Was your universal set a singleton?

Answer (score 1):

You are misinterpreting the link you give (which, in your defense, isn’t particularly well written).

The page tries to show that for subgroups $K\leq H\leq G$, $[G:K]=[G:H][H:K]$ under the added (utterly superfluous) assumption that $H$ has finite index in $G$.

That link considers, essentially, two cases: if $[G:H]$ and $[H:K]$ are both finite; and if $G$ is finite.

These two suffice for the proof if you define the index as either as natural number (when the index is finite) or as $\infty$ (when it is not).

To verify this, note that if $[G:K]$ is infinite, then the first case implies that at least one of $[G:H]$ and $[H:K]$ is infinite, and you get the equality. If $[H:K]$ is infinite, then since every coset of $K$ in $H$ is also a coset of $K$ in $G$, then $[G:K]$ must also be infinite and you get the equality as well. They are clearly eliding this case (which is bad practice, but there you go; it’s a proof wiki, not a particularly reliable source in my opinion). That only leaves the case in which where $[H:K]$ is finite.

If $[G:K]$ is finite, then since a finite index subgroup contains a finite index *normal* subgroup (consider the action of $G$ on the cosets of $K$ by left translation, and look at the kernel of the map into the corresponding symmetric group), then the theorem reduces to the case of $G$ finite (since $N\triangleleft G$ with $N\subseteq K$ gives $[G:K]=[G/N:K/N]$ by the isomorphism theorems), in which situation the second case applies.

Neither one of these cases asserts that if $[G:H]$ is finite then $[H:K]$ must be finite as well, your claimed reading.

---

I will note that the theorem is true if you define the index as *cardinals* (to cover also the infinite case).

The proof is straightforward, which is why I’m always annoyed that books restrict to the finite case or else throw up their hands and say “infinite”.

Let $[G:H]=\kappa$ and $[H:K]=\lambda$. Let $\{g_k\}_{k\in \kappa}$ be a complete set of (left) coset representatives for $H$ in $G$, and let $\{h_{\ell}\}_{\ell\in\lambda}$ be a complete set of (left) coset representatives of $K$ in $H$. I claim that $\{g_kh_{\ell}\}_{(k,\ell)\in \kappa\times\lambda}$ is a complete set of (left) coset representatives for $K$ in $G$.

Indeed, if first let us note that no two of the elements of this set represent the same coset. If $g_kh_{\ell}K = g_rh_sK$, then $g_kh_{\ell}H = g_rh_sH$, hence $g_kH=g_rH$, hence $g_k=g_r$, so $k=r$ (since the $g$ are a complete set of coset representatives for $H$ in $G$). Therefore, $h_{\ell}K=h_sK$, and since the $h$ are a complete set of coset representatives, $h_{\ell}=h_s$ and so $\ell=s$.

Next, let us show every coset is represented. Let $g\in G$. Then there exists $k$ such that $gH = g_kH$. Therefore, $g = g_kh$ for some $h\in H$. And there exists $\ell$ such that $hK = h_{\ell}K$. Therefore, $h=h_{\ell}x$ for some $x\in K$. Thus, $g=g_kh=g_kh_{\ell}x\in g_kh_{\ell}K$. Thus, $gK=g_kh_{\ell}K$. This proves that the collection is a complete set of (left) coset representatives.

Thus, $[G:K] = |\kappa\times\lambda| = |\kappa||\lambda|= [G:H][H:K]$, as claimed. $\Box$

Comment: The statement of the theorem they are proving is: "Let $G$ be a group, let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ with finite index, and let $K$ be a subgroup of $H$." The conclusion they want to prove is that $|G:K| = |G:H| \cdot |H:K|$. The first line of proof 1 assumes that $|H:K|$ is finite, something they did not assume in the statement of the theorem. I do not see what I am missing. In fact, saying that $|H:K|$ is finite is pretty much assuming what they want to prove.

Comment: @Junglemath: They are **assuming** the index is finite. They are not **concluding** the index is finite. Again I ask you for a second reference, since you said you looked “everywhere” and relying on a proof wiki seems.. foolhardy at best. Presumably, they figure you know that if $[H:K]$ is infinite then necessarily $[G:K]$ is infinite and their equality holds.

Comment: Where do you see that they assume $|H:K|$ is finite? Are we reading the same thing?

Comment: @Junglemath: Yes, we are. They assert that $[H:K]=q$ and call this a “hypothesis”. That means they are assuming it. No, that is not a particularly well written proof. Then again, it’s a proof wiki: they aren’t particularly well written. You said “everywhere [you] look[ed].” Where else did you look?

Comment: In every theorem I've ever read, the hypotheses are listed before the start of the proof. Assuming something new in the first line of the actual proof is the most ridiculous thing I've ever seen. "By hypothesis" means by the hypotheses already listed, not by a hypothesis we are about to state.

Comment: @Junglemath: As I said: not a particularly well written proof (though it should be obvious that if $[H:K]$ is infinite then so is $[G:K]$: every coset of $K$ in $H$ is also a coset of $K$ in $G$!) Again I ask: where *else* did you see this alleged conclusion?

Comment: Perhaps I didn't see it explicitly like I did in the link I provided, but you asked for "at least one source", which I provided. And I stand by my assertion that as written, the statement on that page is just plain false.

Comment: Also, can you please edit your answer to include exactly what the statement is that we are trying to prove, and what the assumptions are? I'm just too confused at this point.

Comment: @Junglemath: And then I asked you several times for other places, since you said that you found this assertion “everywhere” you looked. It appears, then, that in fact you found it in one place and one place only. And, again, no, the statement of the theorem in that page is not false, nor does their proof contain the assertion that you insist on reading into it. There is no “just plain false” statement on the page. You can stand by *that* assertion all you want: it won’t make it any less incorrect.

Comment: And do you not see why if $[H:K]$ is *not* finite the entire thing is immediate? Both $[H:K]$ and $[G:K]$ must be infinite then, so that case is trivial. That’s why it is elided in the (not very good) page you link to.

Comment: I do see that, yes. But if they are assuming that $|H:K|$ is finite, they should say so.

Answer (score 0):

This statement is clearly wrong. Take $G=\mathbb{Z}$, $H=2\mathbb{Z}$ and $K=\{0\}$. Then $[G:H]=2$ but $[H:K]=\aleph_0$.

Comment: That was my counterexample too. See the comments in OP.