# Product of subgroup and normal subgroup with prime index

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I am trying to show that for a group $G$ with normal subgroup $N$ with index $[G:N]=p$ (where p is some prime), we have that $HN=G$ if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ which is not contained in $N$.

So:

- $N \unlhd G$
- $[G:N]=p$ for some prime $p$
- $H \leq G$
- $ H \nsubseteq N$
- Want to show that $HN=G$

My shot at a solution is, that since the product of a subgroup and a normal subgroup is again a subgroup, we know that $ HN \leq G .$
Thus, if we can show that $ |HN|=|G|,$ then $HN$ must equal to $G.$

To this end, we could possibly use that $|HN|=\frac{|H||N|}{H \cap N},$ but I didn't succeed with this strategy.

I am aware that $N \unlhd G$ gives us $[G:N]=|G/N|,$ which combined with Lagrange's theorem gives $ |G/N|=\frac{|G|}{|N|}, $ which also might be useful.

Alternatively one could ofcause also try to show that $ HN \geq G,$ but I didn't succeed in doing so either.

Any input will be highly appreciated, thanks in advance! :)

Comment: It is much simpler than you think. Use Lagrange's Theorem to show that if $N \le L \le G$, then either $L = N$, or $L = G$, Then note that $N \lneq H N \le G$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti We are not assuming that $G$ is finite. But I guess we can apply Lagrange to $G/N$.

Comment: True Derek, the exercise doesn't mention that any of the groups are finite, so how could we even justify using Lagrange's theorem?

Comment: At the beginning of the course exercises there might be the assumption that $G$ is a finite group.

Comment: Thanks Derek, I hadn't noticed. Still, one could use the Lagrange-like result about $H\le K \le G$ with $H$ of finite index in $G$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: You can use the so-called “tower law”, that if $H\leq K\leq G$ then $[G:H]=[G:K][K:H]$. This holds in the sense of cardinalities, but you only need it in the finite case here.

Comment: Arturo Magidin, that's what I teach my students, and what I meant in my last comment.

Comment: @Megahyttel As I said in my comment, in this case you know that $N \lhd G$, so you can apply Lagrange to the finite group $G/N$ and deduce that its only subgroups are $N/N$ and $G/N$. But in general you can use the tower law mentioned by Arturo Magidin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** Given a group $G$, and subgroups $H\leq K\leq G$, the following equality holds:
$$[G:H] = [G:K][K:H].$$
Here, $[G:H]$ is the index of $H$ in $G$, which is the number of distinct left (equivalently, right) cosets of $H$ in $G$. This equality holds in the sense of cardinalities (not just in the sense of either finite of $\infty$).

A proof that holds in the sense of cardinalities can be found [in this previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3717421/index-of-subgroup-inside-subgroup-of-finite-index).

Comment: Could this then also be used to prove that [H : H \cap N]=p? (which is actually second part of the excersice that I also struggling with)

Comment: @Megahyttel: Use the Second Isomorphism Theorem for that one.